# Perl grep for a value in column 1

Tags: perl, awk, grep

A system call I'm making in Perl as follows:

```
@filesystems = `/nas/bin/nas_fs -query:TypeNumeric==1:IsRoot==False -fields:RWServers,ROServers,Name,RWMountpoint, -format:%L:%L:%s:%s\\\\n`;
```

works well. It gets me the desired info:

```
server_5::fs_pipeline_950155:/root_vdm_30/fs_pipeline_95015    
:server_7:fs_nfs_esx_wks_vms:    
server_7::fs_ovid3:/fs_ovid3
```

If, however, I want to *really* only populate `@filesystems` with entries for which there's a value in column 1 (i.e. the first value ... lines 1 and 3 in the example above), I'm unsure how to achieve this. `awk -F` through a pipe doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your script after `@filesystems` is populated:

```
# Removes blank lines and lines starting with :
@filesystems = grep { !/(^:|^\s*$/ } @filesystems;
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I suspect that the blank lines were only there by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in Perl itself:

```
my @temp = `/nas/bin/nas_fs -query:TypeNumeric==1:IsRoot==False -fields:RWServers,ROServers,Name,RWMountpoint, -format:%L:%L:%s:%s\\\\n`;
my @filesystems = grep { !/^:/ } @temp;
```

This filters out any entries which begin with a colon from the list.

Alternatively, you could invoke another process:

```
my @filesystems = `/nas/bin/nas_fs <args> | grep -v '^:'`;
```

`grep -v` returns only lines that don't match the pattern, so lines beginning with a colon are excluded.

Comment: I'm really unkeen on 'shelling out' to grep, personally.

Comment: @Sobrique I'm inclined to agree with you in general, although I guess that the preferred option could vary depending on the size of the output of the command.